# How do I fix missing opacity masks in rendered svg files on the HTML5 Canvas

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, html, javascript

I'm currently working on a project that is using the HTML5 Canvas API and I'm encountering a few problems, one of which is disappearing opacity masks used to add texture to an element in Adobe Illustrator.

To be clear, in Illustrator with the transparency menu open I do the following:

- Copy image that I want to mask to clipboard
- Select shape to use as mask
- Click Make Mask
- Click black square and paste image from clipboard

Now I select the artwork and export the selection from the *file* menu.

The resulting svg file can be opened with a browser and renders correctly including the opacity mask, however, if I try to paint this svg file on the canvas via JavaScript and the HTML5 Canvas API anything that is an opacity mask is missing from  the rendered image.

Here is an example image from the browser rendered (file opened with) svg file:
[image]

The door shape with wood effect is the opacity mask;

This is the svg file:

```svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="203" height="257" viewBox="0 0 203 257"><defs><filter id="luminosity-invert" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feColorMatrix values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0"/></filter><mask id="mask" x="15" y="17" width="180" height="260" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><g style="filter:url(#luminosity-invert)"><image width="1920" height="1280" transform="translate(15 17) scale(0.09 0.2)" xlink:href="../../../../Adobe/distressed%20textures/free-templates/9%20Wood%20Textures/Texture1.jpg"/></g></mask></defs><title>opacity-mask</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><g style="mask:url(#mask)"><path d="M19.5,255.5V92.5s11-59,83-59,71,54,71,54v169Z" style="fill:#42210b;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10"/></g><rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="202" height="16" style="fill:#42210b;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10"/></g></g></svg>
```

Now when I try to include this image programmatically on the HTML Canvas the opacity mask is missing and all I get is the solid brown bar (added to test) at the top.

I could paste some code to show this but, the problem is not in code but an underlying problem with rendering opacity masks, for example, if I import the svg file into vectr.com, I experience the same problem.

Does anyone have a clue how to resolve this, I'm flummoxed!

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Comment: I *think* your questions are more about HTML5 Canvas than Illustrator and you *might* get better insight at http://StackOverflow.com .. but I am kind of guessing regarding that. I do know Illustrator is Illustrator, you get what you get. There aren't any real "hidden" user-controllable options for exporting/saving in AI beyond what you see.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is about  the canvas as I explained that the same problem occurs when opening the file in other applications such as vectr at vectr.com and I think there must be some other way to apply textures to images no?

Comment: Well opacity masks are a proprietary AI thing. It's not uncommon for other software to *not* support proprietary features. i.e. Nothing outside of AI supports Meshes either. You often need to "bake in" the unsupported feature (sometimes creating many more vector objects), but I don't know if that's feasible for your usage.

Comment: I think this *is* in fact a coding question. That your SVG doesn't render properly on vectr.com isn't surprising as you link to a JPG file on your local disk which can't be accessed by a website. You should be able to get this working on a local apache server. I've been trying it out but it's giving me trouble. I *am* able to render [this](https://i.imgur.com/LmeuNEm.png) if I link to some nonexistent URL. A "missing link" image inside a mask. So it *is* supported somehow. I *think* the problem could be that the SVG is rendered on the canvas before the image has finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a quick look at the SVG, a guess would be that it's because there's either a missing image file, or the link doesn't point to the location of the image file "Texture1.jpg" on the server.

Looks like it might even be a file located on your own computer rather than an image file on a server.  Do you recognize this file path? `../Adobe/distressed%20textures/free-templates/9%20Wood%20Textures/Texture1.jpg` - is this some template you downloaded to your computer perhaps?

If you *Placed* the image in Illustrator rather than copy pasting it, then it will be a linked file. Perhaps consider embedding it instead. Or alternatively make sure the image file is uploaded to the server, and that the link points to it there. You may have to manually edit the SVG in a text editor to make sure it points to the proper file location.

By the way, using an image as an opacity mask in Illustrator and exporting as an SVG certainly works. Here's [an example I made](https://svgshare.com/i/bb3.svg), but here the image is embedded in the SVG, not as a separate image file.

Comment: The OP wants to render the SVG on an HTML canvas. Here is [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadsWolff/vtjpsx6y/3/) where I render your SVG on an HTML canvas. It works! So the problem must be with the image not loading for several reasons. As I mentioned in a comment I tried to do this locally with a linked image of my own without success, so I'm pretty sure the problem is how to load the image before rendering the SVG on the canvas.

Comment: @Wolff thanks for trying that and showing that an opacity mask does indeed work in that environment, Maybe just using an embedded image is the answer then?  I suppose file size might be an issue, but I should imagine it would be possible to use a pretty small jpeg file.

Comment: @Wolff - found this [question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572560/load-image-from-url-and-draw-to-html5-canvas) - I wonder if this issue is related?

Comment: Yes it's related, but in the linked question it's just the raster image *itself* that hasn't loaded before trying to draw it on a canvas. In this case the SVG is to be regarded as the "image" and the raster image is linked *inside* the SVG. Waiting for the SVG to load before rendering it (like in my jsfiddle) means that the rendering begins immediately when the SVG *markup* has loaded. But the linked raster image hasn't yet loaded and my *theory* is that the problem lies here.

Comment: This is all very useful stuff folks, it is much appreciated.

Comment: This is all very useful stuff folks, it is much appreciated. Billy, yep that's a path to the file on my 'puter I'll have to check out the settings at export time. @wolff splendid job, thanks for proving that it can be done. This is why I posted on this forum rather than stackoverflow, folks here have a much better understanding of the apps designers use. I agree that the file definitely needs to be embedded in the svg, it wouldn't make sense any other way. I'm surprised that that is not the default in the export options. I'll go and test your theory and get back to you all here.

Comment: @Fishbite Embedding is the default behaviour if you copy and paste an image to get it into Illustrator. If you do File > Place, you should choose to disable the "link" option. Then when you export the SVG, the image will be embedded anyway. The reason Illustrator defaults to linking when placing is because Illustrator was technically designed for print work, where placing linked files is generally normal practice.

Comment: @BillyKerr I actually thought I had copied and pasted the image the image into the document as I simply dragged and dropped the file from a folder into the ai document and Windows said "copy". However, when I looked at my layers I could see that indeed the files were linked and not embedded so perhaps dragging and dropping gives me the same result as choosing to Place and image. I don't have any options appear to disable the "link" option though even when I choose "File-->Place" Strange! But thank you to everyone for all the input you've given me.

Comment: @Fishbite, you're welcome. Thanks for making me aware that you can actually draw an SVG file on an HTML canvas. 

Comment: You are more than welcome @wolf. The canvas is a great tool, you can actually play video directly on it, and then do some really crazy stuff programmatically with that video. I'm currently doing some deep research into it with the objective of it being used as a complete page on our website.... Just getting to grips with the graphics side of it at the moment though :)

Comment: @Fishbite - yes, dragging and dropping a raster image file will make it a link too.  Once you have done it you can hit the embed button in the tool options along the top.